# Prune dataset vocabulary

Tags: python, regex, scikit-learn

I have a training and testing dataset from the 20NewsGroups dataset available in sklearn. I have imported the data and created a bag of words that I can use to run it through a naive bayes classifier. Current code is below:

```
def prep(categories):
# Import Newsgroup data
datatrain = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', categories=categories)
datatest = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='test', categories=categories)

countvect = CountVectorizer()  # Create CountVectorizer
Xtrain_counts = countvect.fit_transform(datatrain.data)

tfidf = TfidfTransformer()  # Term-frequency transformer
Xtrain_tfidf = tfidf.fit_transform(Xtrain_counts)
print "\nTfidf Dimensions: %s" % str(Xtrain_tfidf.shape)
print "\nVocabulary: %s" % str(len(countvect.vocabulary_)) + " unique \'words\'"
```

From here, I want to prune the data so that I ignore strings like "w32w" or email IDs or common words like "an", "the", "is" to try and improve the accuracy of my classifier. I have a regex that can catch emails below:

```
found = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', Xtrain_tfidf)
```

How can I apply the regex in such a manner that it *removes* data that matches, and how can I expand the regex to include common words?

String samples:

> From: matt-dah@dsv.su.se (Mattias Dahlberg)
>   Subject: Re: REAL-3D
>   Organization: Dept. of Computer and Systems Sciences, Stockholm University
>   Lines: 17
>   X-Newsreader: TIN [version 1.1 PL8]
>
> Rauno Haapaniemi (raunoh@otol.fi) wrote:
>
> Earlier today I read an ad for REAL-3D animation & ray-tracing software
>   and it looked very convincing to me.
>
> Yes, it looks like very good indeed.
>
> However, I don't own an Amiga and so I began to wonder, if there's a PC
>   version of it.
>
> Nope.

Expected output:

> Mattias Dahlberg REAL-3D Dept of Computer Systems Sciences Stockholm University Rauno Haapaniemi Earlier today read ad for REAL-3D animation & ray-tracing software looked very convincing to me Yes looks like very good indeed However I don't own an Amiga and so began to wonder there's PC version of Nope

From this you can see that the emails, common words, punctuation have all been stripped.

Comment: @S.Jovan added.

Comment: Do you import `from nltk.corpus import stopwords`? You may use `found = re.sub(r"[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+|\b(?:{})\b".format("|".join(set(stopwords.words('english')))), Xtrain_tfidf)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I can get the matches in `found`, but then how do I _remove_ the matched data?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the replacement argument. Try `re.sub(r"[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+|\b(?:{})\b".format("|".join(set(stopwords.words('english')))), '', Xtrain_tfidf)` - just use `re.sub` with a regex that matches stopwords as whole words and email-like substrings.

Comment: Gotcha. can you place that in an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

> `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`
>   Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping occurrences of pattern in string by the replacement repl.

with a regex that matches stopwords as whole words and email-like substrings.

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
result = re.sub(r"[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+|\b(?:{})\b".format("|".join(set(stopwords.words('english')))), '', Xtrain_tfidf)
```

Note the `r''` prefix that defines a raw string literal where `\` defines a literal backslash and `\b` is thus treated as a word boundary, not a backspace char.

The pattern will match:

- `[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+` - 1+ word, `.` or `-` chars, followed with `@` and then again 1+ word, `.` or `-` chars
- `|` - or
- `\b(?:and|or|not|a|an|is|the|of|like)\b` - any of the alternatives in the non-capturing alternation group as whole words as `\b` is a word boundary.